# Typescript search in empty array includes metot

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm searching by the ids in the array. But if the array is empty, I want all the data to come. How can I do it?

```
selectedUrunGrubus: number[] = [];

urun: Urun[];

getUruns() {

this.generic?.Get_All("Uruns/Generic_Method").pipe(map(hizmets => hizmets.filter(hizmets => (this.selectedUrunGrubus.includes(hizmets.urunGrubuID) && this.selectedUrunGrubus.length>0)))).subscribe({
  next: (data) => { this.urun = data; console.log(this.urun) },
  error: (err) => { console.log(err) },
  complete: () => {
  
  }
});
```

}

```
this.urun = [id=1] [id=2] [id=3] [id=4];
if(selectedUrunGrubus == [1,2])
{
this.urun = [id=1] [id=2]
}
if(selectedUrunGrubus == empty)
{
this.urun = [id=1] [id=2] [id=3] [id=4]
}
```

Comment: If selectedUrunGrubus is empty, the urun is empty.
I want to filter only if there is value in selectedUrunGrubus. If there is no value I want the whole urun list to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your array is empty is because of the `this.selectedUrunGrubus.length>0` conditional inside your filter. The length of `selectedUrunGrubus` starts at 0, so the expression will always be `false`.

Here's another strategy you can use. Assign the filtered array to a variable, then return a ternary expression for either case.

```
selectedUrunGrubus: number[] = [];

urun: Urun[];

getUruns() {

this.generic?.Get_All("Uruns/Generic_Method")
  .pipe(
    map(hizmets =>{ 
      const matches = hizmets.filter(hizmet => this.selectedUrunGrubus.includes(hizmet.urunGrubuID));
      return !!matches.length ? matches : hizmets;
    }),
    tap(urun=> this.urun = urun)
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Note:

- I used double bangs `!!` to convert the length into a boolean (since `0` is falsy)
- Use `tap()` to handle side effects like property assignments.
- The rest of your logic inside `subscribe()` is default behavior, so you can just use a basic `subscribe()` at the end.